# What values should be in the catalog in the product type field?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

According to the documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_catalog_field_definition.htm&type=5 , the product type field is required in products catalog.
I cann't understand from the description what exactly should be in this field.
Is this a category?
If so, what happens in cases where there are also subcategories?
If not, what should be in this field?

Thanks.

Comment: this is mostly for streaming updates but it would be product/content/banner

Answer (score 0):

The ProductType is flexible. It is required because you need at least one field that can be a tag in our system, but we don't define what type of data you put in it.  It is a special field because we want to ensure the catalog import is "valid" even if you don't add any additional, custom fields.

Often, retailers will put their main category or product type into that field, but you could just as easily create a category & subcategory field in your catalog so that the naming convention is understood when using that field.

I find most customers use 4-5 or more custom fields depending on their business & products, but others use only the minimum successfully.

Other business types or product types will use it for something different altogether. This is an implementation decision, but don't spend too much time on it.  It acts no different than any custom field in building affinity.